# Grub works but not efistub

Tags: grub2, uefi

There is a grub entry that looks like:

```
... #(the standard insmods and whatnot)
linux /vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=[uuid] rw quiet
initrd /initramfs-linux.img
```

It boots just fine. It works fully as intended.

And I've tried the following efibootmgr entries:

```
efibootmgr -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 -c -L "someuniquelabel" -l /vmlinuz-linux -u "root=UUID=[uuid] rw quiet initrd=/initramfs-linux.img"
efibootmgr -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 -c -L "someuniquelabel" -l /vmlinuz-linux -u "root=UUID=[uuid] rw initrd=/initramfs-linux.img"
efibootmgr -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 -c -L "someuniquelabel" -l /vmlinuz-linux -u "root=PARTUUID=[corresponding partuuid] rw initrd=/initramfs-linux.img"
efibootmgr -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 -c -L "someuniquelabel" -l /vmlinuz-linux -u "root=/dev/nvme0n1p2 rw initrd=/initramfs-linux.img"
```

And not a single one of them works.

According to `efibootmgr -v`:

```
Boot0000 ... HD([X])/File(\vmlinuz-linux)...
Boot0001 ... HD([X])/File(\EFI\grub\grubx64.efi)
Boot0003 ... HD([X])/File(\vmlinuz-linux)...
Boot0004 ... HD([X])/File(\vmlinuz-linux)...
Boot0005 ... HD([X])/File(\vmlinuz-linux)...quiet...
```

So the X is the same in each one, so I don't think the -d and -p arguments were wrong when I was making the efibootmgr entries. uuid matches up, so that's probably not the big problem either.

Yet my boot entries never boot! It constantly says something about "VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)" (kernel panic) (but I have no idea what this means or how to fix it).

EDIT: all uuids ARE lower case in my entries.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you verified the existence of the files referenced in  your `efibootmgr -v` output?

Comment: The error message comes from the kernel, so the kernel has started. The error tells us that the kernel cannot, for some unknown reason, find the root file system. Double check the UUIDs. The last entry `root=UUID=/dev/nvme0n1p2` is clearly wrong, since an UUID string is expected after uuid=.

Comment: One gotcha is that the UUIDs must be lowercased. The `gdisk` program prints them in upper case. To add to the confusion, even the comment in the kernel source file `init/do_mounts.c` shows an example UUID in upper case.

Comment: @JohanMyréen `root=UUID=/dev/nvme0n1p2` was a typeo, I made the entry with `root=/dev/nvme0n1p2`. Also, all of the UUIDs ARE lower case (same as in grub). @ElderGeek Yeah, they definitely exist. And they're the same as the files referenced by grub, and grub boots them just fine.

Comment: I had the same problem, and decided that the EFI system was not passing the option to kernel. In the end, I had to use the built-in command line option in my own compiled kernel.